# In pyomo, any reason for using "model.<nameofvariable>" throughout the code instead of doing "<nameofvariable> = model.<nameofvariable>" and using it?

Tags: python, pyomo

The question is a bit self explanatory I believe, but just to give a simple example (this is not the entire model of course):

```
model = AbstractModel()
model.i = Set()
model.j = Set(initialize=model.i)
model.R = Param(model.i)

def lowband(model,i):
    return (model.R[i],100)
model.x = Var(model.i, bounds=lowband, within=NonNegativeReals, initialize=0)
model.y = Var(model.i, bounds=lowband, within=NonNegativeReals, initialize=0)
model.W = Var( bounds=(0,100), within=NonNegativeReals, initialize=0)
model.L = Var( bounds=(0,100), within=NonNegativeReals, initialize=0)

def rule_eq1(model,i,j):
    if i>j:
        return (model.x[i]-model.x[j])**2+(model.y[i]-model.y[j])**2 >=(model.R[i]+model.R[j])**2
    else:
        return Constraint.Skip;
model.eq1 = Constraint(model.i,model.j,rule=rule_eq1)
```

I get really annoyed by the variable and parameter names in the constraint declarations because of the `model.` part. If after each declaration we do something like:

```
x = model.x
y = model.y
```

and so on and use "x" and "y" instead of the original name, it works just fine too. However, the vast majority of pyomo models I see on the internet follow that approach of always using `model.`. Is there any good reason for doing this and that I still haven't realised? I think it makes the code writing process worse and it also gets harder to read the code

Comment: Agreed. Similar to the "self.blah" in python or the "this.blah" in javascript. Especially in formulas it reduces readability

Comment: I understand you are new to Python.

Comment: OR-community-discord-server: https://discord.gg/k5AtFccjne join us to get a bigger live-community.

Answer (score 1):

When you say model.x then you know that this x is a part of the model
but

if you see
model.x-X==2
what  can you say about the X ?
is it a constant ? constant in the model ? var in the model ?

This also applies to naming the variables
if you use model.i it works
alternatively,
if you use model.generators it works as well!
but in the second case it is more clear and easier to understand

Comment: But isn't that issue present anyways even if we keep using "model."? In the example above, we have model.x and model.R, a variable and a parameter, respectively. The "model." adds no extra information here